# Set QBoxLayout maximum size?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

I clearly missing something here, please enlighten me.

```
AttributeError: 'QVBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setMaximumSize'
```

I've been reading the Qt Docs for a while but just cant seem to be able to get this to work

Comment: To clarify a bit here, I have a base QVBoxLayout, to which I have addLayout'ed another QVBoxLayout, I am trying to set the maximum width of the inner QVBoxLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can't set a maximal size for a layout. Why would you want to - it makes no sense to me (which child widget should the layout limit?)

Regarding `setMaximumSize` - there's no such method for layouts. There is however, a `QLayout::SetMaximumSize` constraint which you can set, but this constraint applies to the widget that's laid out with this layout, not to the layout itself. It means that the widget can grow no larger than the maximal size of the layout - so this is quite different from what you need.

I recommend you re-think your real goal - perhaps it can be achieved in some other way. For instance, you can set the maximal size for the individual widgets laid out by your `QBoxLayout`.

Comment: You are right, I was approaching it wrong, I needed to set a maxiumum width for the relevant widget, then have the other content expand as needed, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the [maximumSize](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qboxlayout.html#maximumSize) property directly as it is dynamically determined by the layout. Perhaps you are trying to set the [QLayout.SizeConstraint](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum) to QLayout.SetMaximumSize? If so, then see the [QLayout.setSizeConstraint](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlayout.html#setSizeConstraint) method. Otherwise, you should call [QWidget.setMaximumSize](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#setMaximumSize) if you want to specify an exact maximum for a given widget.

Answer (score 0):

Just as that error tells you, there is no `setMaximumSize` method on a layout.

`QWidget`s have that method.